# paper-drawer-panel's closeDrawer() not closing with custom header element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**UPDATE** I was able to close the drawer with `document.querySelector('paper-drawer-panel').forceNarrow = true;`. I was going to delete this question but maybe I will leave this up to see if there is a way to do this proper with `closeDrawer()`

I wrote my own custom header, which doesn't use any of the paper header behaviors. It's just it's own custom element html styled header with no behavior or features.

I implemented `paper-drawer-panel` which worked great with my custom header. However, I can not get `closeDrawer()` to close the drawer. I see the function itself is `function () { this.selected = 'main' }`, but not sure how that applies to the inner code of `paper-drawer-panel`.

How can I make `paper-drawer-panel`'s  `closeDrawer()` to close the drawer?

index.html:

```
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-drawer-panel>
      <div drawer>
        <drawer-custom></drawer-custom>
      </div>
      <div main>
        <header-custom></header-custom>
        <video-selection data-route="home" tabindex="-1"></video-selection>
      </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
  </template>
```

---

app/elements/drawer-custom.html:

```
<dom-module id="drawer-custom">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
     :host {
       background-color: var(--brown-color);
       height: 1000px;
       width: 100%;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       outline: none;
       display: block;
       padding-right: 1px;
        --iron-icon-height: 42px;
        --iron-icon-width: 42px;
     }

    .v-center {
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      @apply(--layout-center-center);
    }



    #close-drawer {
      height: 130px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: var(--pink-color);
      padding-right: 1px;
    }

    #contact {
      background-color: #a9483b;
      height: 130px; 
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 1px;
    }

    </style>
    <div on-click="_closeDrawer" id="close-drawer" class="v-center">
      <iron-icon src='../images/menu-button-close.svg'></iron-icon>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      contact
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'drawer-custom',
      _closeDrawer: function() {
        document.querySelector('paper-drawer-panel').closeDrawer();
      } 
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

when I added `<paper-icon-button>` as a child to `paper-drawer-panel` then the function `closeDrawer()` worked.